# Link in a tag wiki summary not displayed as an actual link

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, tag-wiki, tag-excerpt

On [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/), you can see that the link in the excerpt is not an actual click-able link : it is displayed as a "regular" text, like the one you are reading right now. [Here is a screenshot with the excerpt in a red box, and the bugged link in black box.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrt2A.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

There is no HTML markup in the excerpts by design.

Excerpts are short descriptions of the tag: they are not meant for clicking on another link since they are just short descriptions that you read to get an idea of what the tag is about.

Reference links should be placed in the full tag wiki, which is located at `http://stackoverflow.com/tags/[tagName]/info`, where `[tagName]` is the name of a tag.